# Retrieve posts from firebase database using a field within the child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

[project tree image in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs8gu.jpg)

I am developing a social media app

In the Firebase database,
There will be Users node,posts node,likes node and request type nodes

Users nodes contains fields which represents users details and it has a uid which is like a key

Under the posts node, there will be a postskey within it there will be the details of the posts like uid,profileimage,postimage, description,date,time,fullname
The uid in the posts node is the uid in the Users node

I successfully uploaded images into the firebase storage and its url would be in the postimage field within the child node

To retrieve the particular users posts and display it in the particular users profile I tried this code which I enclosed in the images

But the posts of the user doesn't shows and white blank activity only shows up

Can u guide me to achieve my expected result
I am not good in English
Sorry,if you cannot understand my question because of my poor English

within OnCreate ,

```
mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
currentUserID=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
PostsRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts");
myPostsList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.my_all_posts_list);
myPostsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager=new LinearLayoutManager(this);
linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
myPostsList.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
DisplayMyAllPosts();
```

within Displaymyallposts method

```
private void DisplayMyAllPosts() {
    Query myPostsQuery=PostsRef.orderByChild("uid").startAt(currentUserID).endAt(currentUserID+"\uf8ff");
    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Posts> options=new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Posts>().setQuery(myPostsQuery,Posts.class).build();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts,MyPostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Posts, MyPostsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyPostsViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Posts model) {
            holder.fullname.setText(model.getFullname());
            holder.date.setText(model.getDate());
            holder.time.setText(model.getTime());
            holder.description.setText(model.getDescription());
            Picasso.get().load(model.getProfileimage()).into(holder.profileimage);
            Picasso.get().load(model.getPostimage()).into(holder.postImage);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public MyPostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view=LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_posts_layout,viewGroup,false);
            MyPostsViewHolder viewHolder=new MyPostsViewHolder(view);
            return viewHolder;
        }
    };
   myPostsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}

public static class MyPostsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView fullname,date,time,description;
    CircleImageView profileimage;
    ImageView postImage;
    public MyPostsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        fullname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_user_name);
        date=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        time=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_time);
        description=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_description);
        profileimage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_profile_image);
        postImage=itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_image);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your code rather than posting as an image.

Comment: Post you code and your firebase databas format.

Comment: now i added database tree in the link

Comment: Did you start listening for changes?

Comment: I have created a separate module class called as.   Posts.java which is initialised with getters and setters to get and set the database values

Comment: @Alex Mamo I forgot to give startlistening tq for making me to know my silly mistakes

Comment: @Alex Mamo The image is still not displaying it still seems blank but other data are displaying except image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post is retrieved
it's because of my silly mistakes
I forgot to give startlistening
That's the reason for not been able to retrieve the post
But there is an another problem
Except the image all other fields are displaying
But not the image
The image is still blank